# $|f(x)| \le |x|^\frac53$ for all $x$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $|f(x)| \le |x|^\frac53$ for all $x$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.

I have no idea where to begin with this question, can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Note that $f(0)=0$. Then consider the absolute value of $\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$.

Answer (score 1):

From this $f(0) = 0$. So $|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}| \leq |x|^{2/3} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. So $f'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$|f'(0)|=|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}| \le |\lim_{h\to 0} h^\frac{2}{3}|=0$

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, however can you explain the step you did to get to that answer, im not to sure why we have to do that.

Comment: I'm using squeeze theorem here $|f'(x)|$ is squeezed between $0$ and $0$ so that $|f'(0)|=0$